# Change VsCode project tree appearance like web storm

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I want to change vs code project tree arrow up looks like Webstorm

[image: my vscode]

I want this :

[image: webstorm]

Comment: Did you try searching for WebStorm themes in VSCode extensions category? (Press Ctrl+Shift+X in VS Code).

Comment: change the svg's used for the fold markers